# How to determine closeness of relationships in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am developing a facebook app that publishes some random jokes directed at the user's three close friends.

Obviously this does not work well with random people picked up from the friends list.

How do I go about implementing this?

EDIT:

To be more precise, what open graph protocol should I use?

Answer (score 1):

hy I think you should use FQL http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/. There are many tables like comments, message, comments_into, photo tag where user id is involved. I think you can get the number of communications between the users.

Answer (score 0):

The number of communications directed between the accounts should serve as a general scale of closeness.

Comment: But how do we get the number of communications between accounts? from the open graph protocol?